# To start an oracle ASM instance generates an error

Tags: security, authentication, oracle11g

Can anyone help me overcome this message while starting `asm` instance?

> ora-01031 insufficient privileges

I perform a task to create an `asm` instance using `start asm instance
oradim -new -sid +asm`.

Here are the steps I take, starting from `connect` to `sqlplus` within `cmd` like:

step 1> `sqlplus /nolog`

then I connect successfully and try some different ways to login, like below:

```
SQL> connect / as sysdba;
ERROR:
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

SQL> conn / as sysdba;
ERROR:
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

SQL> conn / as sysasm;
ERROR:
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

SQL> connect / as sysasm;
ERROR:
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
```

Answer (score 0):

You must be in the DBA Unix group to

```
connect / as sysdba
```

For

```
connect / as sysasm
```

your Oracle ID must be `ops$unixname` and the dba must have 
granted sysasm role to `ops$unixname`.

IE: If your Unix ID is `fred`, and you have an Oracle ID of `ops$fred` then the DBA would do a

```
grant sysasm to ops$fred;
```

Then you could connect with

```
connect / as sysasm;
```